# How to automatically disable dates after got selected via calender #jQuery #Drupal8

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-8

I have created custom form for drupal 8 site and taken date type field. i want to disable dates after got selected like booked some slot types. i have seen so many codes which uses .datepicker(). but when i use this code it shows two calenders. i want to use jQuery for it. please give some suggestions

Thankyou

Comment: Can you add the code which you have tried for better explanation of the issue you are facing? Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to disable the date field after selecting the date using jQuery. Hope the following code can help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
        onSelect: function() {
            $('#datepicker').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }

    });
});


});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" ></p>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the reference](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)